# NuxtJS vuex state variables don't keep the updated values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building `nuxtjs` app with vuex support, I added fetch hook in one of my app pages, when I load the app for the first time it fires the hook which dispatch vuex action and change the state of integer variables, but when I refresh the page or go to different page all the state variables return to its initial value.

Page code: `pages/components.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Total {{ total }}</h1>
    <h3>Number 1 {{ number_one }}</h3>
    <h3>Number 2 {{ number_two }}</h3>
    <h3>Number 3 {{ number_three }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    name: "components",
    head() {
      return {
        title: 'Components Page'
      }
    },
     async fetch({ store, error }) {
      try {
         await store.dispatch('cdata/fetchData');
      } catch (e) {
        error({
          statusCode: 503,
          message: 'Unable to fetch data at this time, please try again later.'
        });
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        total: state => state.cdata.total,
        number_one: state => state.cdata.number_one,
        number_two: state => state.cdata.number_two,
        number_three: state => state.cdata.number_three,
      }),
    }
  }
</script>
```

vuex store module: `store/cdata.js`

```
import ComponentService from '~/services/Covid19Service.js';

export const state = () => ({
  total: 0,
  number_one: 0,
  number_two: 0,
  number_three: 0
});

export const mutations = {
  SET_COMPONENTS_DATA(state, payload){
    state.total = payload.total;
    state.number_one = payload.number_one;
    state.number_two = payload.number_two;
    state.number_three = payload.number_three;
  }
}

export const actions = {
  fetchData({ commit }){
    ComponentService.getData().then(response => {
      commit('SET_COMPONENTS_DATA', response.data);
    });
  }
}
```

ComponentService is an axios service: `services/ComponentService.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: `/api`,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

export default {
  getData() {
    return apiClient.get('/cdata');
  }
}
```

In which part I made a mistake, please advice

Comment: Is persisting the state through local storage an option for you? https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: that's a good solution, but is this (not persisting the state) is the normal functionality of `vuex` store?

Comment: Yes, vuex is built for SPA usage, so it does not persist the state out of the box. However `vuex-persistedstate` works great, we use it in production.

Comment: I have other issue I couldn't understand, when I start the nuxt app it loads the data correctly and after I click refresh button the values become zero (the api is never called) and become like this till I  shutdown the app and start it again, but when I dispatch the action in the mounted hook the api called correctly and fill the values, so my question why when I put the api call in fetch hook the api called once but whenever I put it in mounted it called everytime the page is loaded? please advice.

Comment: It's hard to answer based only on your text. Could you share the code or create a new question?

Comment: this is my repo https://github.com/yabasha/tracker check `pages/components.vue`